# Missing Smokie Robot - URDF file from ROS, MoveIt!

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

In the Smokie -MoveIt ROS tutorial
( http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/OUR/MoveIt%20Setup%20Assistant%20for%20OUR%20robot)

says that you need to load the OUR-II.URDF file, which I can not find!!

Does anyone has this file (OUR-I.URDF is also good!)

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225545/missing-smokie-robot---urdf-file-from-ros,-moveit!/) by [AkosTar](https://answers.ros.org/users/25810/akostar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest you take this up with OUR themselves. [wiki.ros.org/Robots/OUR](http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/OUR) points to [LMNcnu/OUR_6DoFs](https://github.com/LMNcnu/OUR_6DoFs), which has an [issue tracker](https://github.com/LMNcnu/OUR_6DoFs/issues).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AkosTar](https://answers.ros.org/users/25810/akostar/) on 2016-02-01**:
Thank you! I put my issue into the issue tracker.

But i hope someone else has this file... I really need it...thanks